# The description of Hurwitz groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, group-actions

Let $G$ be a Hurwitz group, i.e. the automorphism group of some [Hurwitz surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_surface) $C$. Then [Hurwitz's automorphisms theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_automorphisms_theorem) shows that the quotient map of $C$ by $G$ has ramification points of indices $2$, $3$ and $7$. My question is how to deduce that $G$ is generated by elements $x$ and $y$ satisfying $x^2=y^3=(xy)^7=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition, the quotient $C/G$ is the orbifold $O=S^2(2,3,7)$: Sphere with 3 cone points with point-stabilizers $Z_2, Z_3, Z_7$. Thus, the fundamental group $\pi$ of $O$ has the presentation
$$
\langle a, b, c| a^2, b^3, c^7, abc\rangle. 
$$
(You can prove it by appealing to van Kampen theorem for instance, or by looking at the fundamental domain for the action of $\pi$ on the universal cover.) The usual covering theory applies to orbifolds, so every covering of $O$ is given by a subgroup in $\pi$. Regular coverings correspond to normal subgroups $N$ in $\pi$, so the quotient group is $\pi/N$ (same as the deck-group $G$ in your question) has the properties you need.